# Iterating through an RDD without doing any changes to it

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

So I have a RDD, this RDD is paired together with indexes of its elements. I would like to simply iterate over it (or maybe if there is a nice Spark function to do this) and check adjacent elements by comparing one of their values. If the adjacent elements fulfill this check, I would like to note down their indexes in a different non RDD structure, maybe a ListBuffer.

Is this possible to do with some kind of Spark special function or do I have to simply iteratue through it manually, and how would I then iterate through it?

Comment: you cannot just iterate an RDD and comparing adjacent elements... you would  have to join the RDD with itself (with join condition index = index-1 or so). Why don't you convert it to a Dataset/Dataframe, there you could lead/lag window functions ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the difference between dataset and dataframe and which would you think may fit my needs betteR?

Comment: datasets are always better in terms of performance and type safety. But from programming point of view dataframe is user friendly.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I already started on datasets and it seems somewhat straight forward for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the main characteristics of an RDD is that it is immutable. Once it is created, you can iterate over it as many times as you want, but you won't be able to make any changes to it.

If you want to make changes, you need to create a new RDD via a transformation.

Additionally, if you want to iterate over an RDD and check adjacent elements, this logic will most likely not work very well as an RDD is distributed and you will usually not be able to have any guarantee of which records are next to each other. You could control by specifying a partitioner to group your data, but still I wouldn't count on it unless you explicitly use a function to group your data.

If you post some sample data it may be easier to help you with your question.